# get the value of input type text in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, doc

In front page I have a input with type text. A button is created aside it. When button is clicked, in js I want to use the text in the input. But I get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

frontpage:

```
New Name: <input type="text" name="newName" value= "blahblah"  >    </input>
<button id="submitNewName">OK!</button>
```

Js:

```
$("#submitNewName").live('click',function(){
alert(document.getElementById('newName').value);
});
```

Comment: Use `getElementByName`, not `getElementById`. But can easily be done by JQuery

Comment: `getElementsByName`, not `getElementByName`. This will return an array of elements

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using? `live()` has been deprecated for years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `attribute selector` to grab the element,

```
$("#submitNewName").on('click',function(){
   alert($('[name=newName]').val());
});
```

As well as, don't use `live()` since it was deprecated in recent versions of jquery

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/np8zs1yv/)

Comment: assumes that OP is using a version that supports `on()`. Could be working on an old project that hasn't been upgraded

Comment: I upgraded Jquery and then this code solved my problem, thanks

Comment: @mohammadeslahisani Glad to help you. :)